How to let nswag generated openapi server code to perform validation (enum. required field as specified at the yaml)
I am using nswag to generate the openapi server code based on an yaml by something below.
<Exec Command="dotnet $(PkgNSwag_MSBuild)/tools/Net60/dotnet-nswag.dll openapi2cscontroller /input:./Yaml/BookStore.yaml ... />

so that I can implement the server side handler like below
public override async Task<ActionResult<CreateBookResponse>> CreateBook([FromBody] Book body)

I can call the endpoint (say, a POST one) successfully by putting a json as request body.
The problem is that, I defined some enums and required fields for the request body in the yaml. The request can still reach my server side handler with the request body being Null or an required enum being 0 (so it is the first value of the enum as defined in the yaml) if the field is not specified at the request body.
I can imagine why it become null, most likely it is because the json (when not comply with the specified format) cannot be converted to the c# object.
But my problem is that, instead of passing a null request body to me without a reason.
Could I ask the nswag generated server code to perform the validation as defined in the yaml (like required field, enum value checking, etc.) and return meaning validation error to the client?
